# can't make the dropdown feed by PHP and MYSQLI to work

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, dropdown

I've done more than a dozen like this, but somehow it does not work.

my code is:

```
 $query_locals = "SELECT * FROM TbLocal LEFT JOIN TbFraccao ON TbLocal.PkLocal=TbFraccao.FkLocal LEFT JOIN TbTipo ON TbFraccao.FkTipo=TbTipo.PkTipo ORDER BY TbLocal.LocalNome, TbFraccao.FraccaoNome";
$result_locals = mysqli_query($conn, $query_locals);

$lista_locals="";

      while($row_local = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_locals))
      {$lista_locals = $lista_locals . '<option value="' . $row_local['PkFraccao'] . '"> ' . $row_local['LocalNome'] . "- ". $row_local['TipoNome'] . " - ". $row_local['FraccaoNome'] ."</option>";

        echo $row_local['LocalNome']. "<br>";
      };


echo "lista de locais -  " . $lista_locals;
```

the echo `$row_local['LocalNome']. "<br>";` is working but the `echo "lista de locais -  " . $lista_locals;` is not... any guess??

- I already tried the query straight in my DB and it's working fine.
- I have already conformed all the columns names.

And this is the form part:

```
<div >
  <label class="control-label " for="local">Local</label>
  <select class="select form-control" id="local" name="local" >

  <?php 
  echo $lista_fraccoes;?>
  </option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: initialize `$lista_locals='';` like this

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Having the `_local` postfix on each of your variables is a habit that's going to become quirky to the point of obnoxious. Almost all the variables you'll be working with are "local". Global variables should be the exception, and avoided if at all possible.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "not working". Do you mean "doesn't get data" or "doesn't display anything at all"? Remember "not working" is the least useful diagnostic you can give, so be more specific.

Comment: in my query '_local' is the refer to place, its the translation to portuguese.

By not working i mean that 'echo "lista de locais -  " . $lista_locals;' does not print anything

Comment: remove the extra semicolon `;` after the `while` loop

Comment: Check if it going inside while loop and you are getting any data from your query or not?

Comment: that's why i have the 'echo $row_local['LocalNome'] . "<br>";' inside the loop. And it works

Comment: `<option>` is supposed to be inside `<select>`.

Comment: It might be converting printing your html, try checking in inspect element. Might be you will se the options printed there.

Comment: Use `View Source`, do you still think it's not working?

Comment: Thank you Kamal Paliwal. It was printing (just took of one of the "<" and it printed out... now just have to figure out why it's not showing in the dropdown! but at least i know that i have the data!

Comment: it's not showing in the what dropdown? There's no `<select>` element shown in your code. You'd have to (at minimum) `echo "<select>".$lista_locals."</select>"` before it would do that.

Comment: the dropdown was down further in the code. Already corrected that in the question. Thank you ADyson

Comment: Ok thanks. Well you're echoing a different variable into that, so it won't have the right data in it. That would explain why it doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing select tag in this, try using select tag and append options inside select. Currently this is rendering options as html but it won't look like dropdown as select is missing.

```
$lista_locals='<select name="XYZ">';
while($row_local = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_locals)) {
    $lista_locals = $lista_locals . '<option value="' . $row_local['PkFraccao'] . '"> ' . $row_local['LocalNome'] . "- ". $row_local['TipoNome'] . " - ". $row_local['FraccaoNome'] ."</option>";

    echo $row_local['LocalNome']. "<br>";
};
$lista_locals = $lista_locals . "</select>";
echo "lista de locais -  " . $lista_locals;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The `echo $lista_locais`; was not working because the html browser was interpreting it as being html.

Once I removed one of th "`<`" from the `<option value=' . $row_local['PkFraccao'] . '>` it printed out the list of entries for the select options!

Solved by Kamal Paliwal in the comments